# Restriction of Cartier divisors

Tags: algebraic-geometry, divisors-algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ be a smooth variety, $D=\{(U_{i},f_{i})\}$ a Cartier divisor on $X$ and $V$ a closed subvariety of $X$. Define $D|_{V}$ as the restriction of $D$ to $V$.

I have two questions:

1. When is $D|_{V}$ a Cartier divisor?
2. When $D|_{V}$ is a Cartier divisor, how does one write it down in the form like $D$?

Comment: For 2. take $\{(U_i \cap V,f_i{|V})\}$

Comment: Cartier divisors `restrict' to Cartier divisors in the sense that any Cartier divisor correspond to a line bundle with a rational section. The line bundle restricts, the rational section may not. So, you always get a line bundle by restriction.

Comment: @JacobGross I was thinking either that or pulling back along the canonical inclusion map $V\hookrightarrow X$

Comment: @BenP. Ah, yes you mean pulling back the line bundle? I think this amounts to the same thing. I wrote $\{U_i\cap V_i, f_i|V\}$ because of the phrasing "in a form like D."

Comment: @JacobGross good, I'm trying to avoid using line bundles in what I'm doing so this is helpful. Although the pullback along the inclusion (call it $\iota$) look like $\{(\iota^{-1}(U_{i}),f_{i}\circ\iota)\}$ is this still the same thing. Though this could be problematic if it turns out that $\iota$ isn't dominant.